# Time Efficient gap filling data in dataframe using .NET for Spark

Tags: c#, dataframe, apache-spark, .net-spark

I would like to fill gaps in my `DataFrame` using .NET for Spark.

The current `DataFrame (rawData)` contains data on a minute interval between `reportFrom` and `reportTo`

```
DateTime reportFrom = new DateTime(2021, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime reportTo = new DateTime(2021, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0);
```

Some intervals are missing and I would like to fill them in with the last known value.

```
+----+-----+---+----+------+------------------+--------------------+------------------+
|Year|Month|Day|Hour|Minute|Id                |                Type|             Value|
+----+-----+---+----+------+------------------+--------------------+------------------+
|2021|    3|  4|   0|     0|                87|               Power|               0.0|
|2021|    3|  4|   0|     1|                87|               Power|               0.0|
|2021|    3|  4|   0|     2|                87|               Power|               0.0|
...
|2021|    3|  4|  14|     2|                87|               Power|             380.0|
|2021|    3|  4|  14|     3|                87|               Power|             380.0|
|2021|    3|  4|  14|     4|                87|               Power|             380.0|
|2021|    3|  4|  14|     5|                87|               Power|             380.0|
|2021|    3|  4|  14|     7|                87|               Power|             380.0|
...
|2021|    3|  4|  22|     7|                87|               Power|               0.0|
```

The result I am expecting after the first step (inserting missing minutes) is:

```
+----+-----+---+----+------+------------------+--------------------+------------------+
|Year|Month|Day|Hour|Minute|Id                |                Type|             Value|
+----+-----+---+----+------+------------------+--------------------+------------------+
|2021|    3|  4|   0|     0|                87|               Power|               0.0|
|2021|    3|  4|   0|     1|                87|               Power|               0.0|
|2021|    3|  4|   0|     2|                87|               Power|               0.0|
...
|2021|    3|  4|  14|     2|                87|               Power|             380.0|
|2021|    3|  4|  14|     3|                87|               Power|             380.0|
|2021|    3|  4|  14|     4|                87|               Power|             380.0|
|2021|    3|  4|  14|     5|                87|               Power|             380.0|
|2021|    3|  4|  14|     6|              null|                null|              null|
|2021|    3|  4|  14|     7|                87|               Power|             380.0|
|2021|    3|  4|  14|     8|              null|                null|              null|
...
|2021|    3|  4|  23|    59|              null|                null|              null|
```

So far, I used to create a new `DataFrame` with all the minutes and then performing `left outer Join` on both dataframes.

```
int inc = 1;
List<DateTime> timeList = new List<DateTime>();
while (reportFrom < reportTo)
{
    timeList.Add(reportFrom);
    reportFrom = reportFrom.AddMinutes(inc);
}    

var toFillTime0 = new List<object> { -1, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

var dataToFill = spark.CreateDataFrame(
    new List<GenericRow> { new GenericRow(toFillTime0.ToArray()) },
    new StructType(                     //shema
    new List<StructField>()
    {
            new StructField("Year0", new IntegerType()),
            new StructField("Month0", new IntegerType()),
            new StructField("Day0", new IntegerType()),
            new StructField("Hour0", new IntegerType()),
            new StructField("Minute0", new IntegerType()),
    }));

foreach (DateTime time in timeList)
{

    var toFillTime = new List<object> { time.Year, time.Month, time.Day, time.Hour, time.Minute };

    var dataToFillt = spark.CreateDataFrame(
        new List<GenericRow> { new GenericRow(toFillTime.ToArray()) },
        new StructType(                     //shema
        new List<StructField>()
        {
            new StructField("Year0", new IntegerType()),
            new StructField("Month0", new IntegerType()),
            new StructField("Day0", new IntegerType()),
            new StructField("Hour0", new IntegerType()),
            new StructField("Minute0", new IntegerType()),
        }));

    dataToFill = dataToFill.Union(dataToFillt);

}

dataToFill = dataToFill.Filter("Year0 > 0");    

var toFillReportDataReq = dataToFill.Join(rawData,
                dataToFill["Year0"] == update10["Year"] & dataToFill["Month0"] == update10["Month"] & dataToFill["Day0"] == update10["Day"]
                & dataToFill["Hour0"] == update10["Hour"] & dataToFill["Minute0"] == update10["Minute"], "left_outer");
```

A few rows of `toFillReportDataReq` are shown bellow:

```
|2021|    3|  4|  22|     4|                87|               Power|               0.0|
|2021|    3|  4|  22|     5|                87|               Power|               0.0|
|2021|    3|  4|  22|     6|                87|               Power|               0.0|
|2021|    3|  4|  22|     7|                87|               Power|               0.0|
|2021|    3|  4|  22|     8|              null|                null|              null|
|2021|    3|  4|  22|     9|              null|                null|              null|
|2021|    3|  4|  22|    10|              null|                null|              null|
|2021|    3|  4|  22|    11|              null|                null|              null|
|2021|    3|  4|  22|    12|              null|                null|              null|
|2021|    3|  4|  22|    13|              null|                null|              null|
|2021|    3|  4|  22|    14|              null|                null|              null|
```

The replacement of null values in the column `Values` is already covered using `window` and `last` function.

The values in columns `Id` and `Type` are replaced with `var id = 87` and "Power" using

```
toFillReportDataReq = toFillReportDataReq.WithColumn("Id", Functions.When(toFillReportDataReq["Id"].IsNull(), id)
   .Otherwise(toFillReportDataReq["Id"]))
   .WithColumn("Type", Functions.When(toFillReportDataReq["Type"].IsNull(), "Power")
    .Otherwise(toFillReportDataReq["Type"]));
```

This method returns the results I want, but it is very time consuming (inefficient).

My questions are following:

- Is there a more sufficient way to create a new `DataFrame` containing all the minutes between the intervals specified?
- Is there any way to avoid Join in this method?
- What is the best way to define all the values in the column Id to id and Type to "Power"?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m not near a pc at the moment so will try and do an example tomorrow. If it was me I would find out how many minutes I need to project (date diff in minutes) then do spark.Range(numberOfMinutes). Left outer join that to your data frame and WithColumn id from range and date add minutes start time to that id - if you can avoid calling spark in a loop then it will be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I will try as suggested. I would appreciate if you could post your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach I would take:

1. Build a DataFrame that has a row for every minute you want to represent (I used spark.Range to project a row for every minute I need)
2. For each ID from Range, add one minute to the start date
3. Join the date's to your original data frame using a left_outer join so you don't lose any rows
4. Then use Last to fill in any gaps - note if you start with a null, the newValue will be null until you get some data

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Spark.Sql;
using Microsoft.Spark.Sql.Expressions;
using Microsoft.Spark.Sql.Types;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var spark = SparkSession.Builder().GetOrCreate();
            
            //Sample data set - we will fill in the missing minutes
            var df = spark.CreateDataFrame(new List<GenericRow>()
            {
                new GenericRow(new object[] {2021, 3, 4, 8, 3, 87, "Type1", 380.5}),
                new GenericRow(new object[] {2021, 3, 4, 8, 10, null, null, null}),
                new GenericRow(new object[] {2021, 3, 4, 8, 20, null, null, null}),
                new GenericRow(new object[] {2021, 3, 4, 8, 25, null, null, null}),
                new GenericRow(new object[] {2021, 3, 4, 8, 35, 87, "Type1", 0.0}),
                new GenericRow(new object[] {2021, 3, 4, 8, 45, 87, "Type1", 0.0})
            }, new StructType(new List<StructField>()
            {
                new StructField("Year", new IntegerType()),
                new StructField("Month", new IntegerType()),
                new StructField("Day", new IntegerType()),
                new StructField("Hour", new IntegerType()),
                new StructField("Minute", new IntegerType()),
                new StructField("ID", new IntegerType()),
                new StructField("Type", new StringType()),
                new StructField("Value", new DoubleType()),
            }));
            
            //start and end time
            var reportFrom = new DateTime(2021, 3, 4, 7, 0, 0);
            var reportTo = new DateTime(2021, 3, 4, 9, 0, 0);
            
            //convert start time to unix epoch as we can't pass a DateTime to spark (yet!)
            var unixFromTime = (reportFrom - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds;
            
            //how many total rows do we need?
            var minutesToCreate = reportTo.Subtract(reportFrom).TotalMinutes;
            
            //create a dataframe with 1 row for every minute we need
            var everyMinute = spark.Range((long) minutesToCreate);
            
            //Add the reportFrom unix epoch
            everyMinute = everyMinute.WithColumn("BaseTime", Functions.Lit(unixFromTime));
            
            //add to the unix epoch, the Id (incrementing number) multiplied by 60 - if we didn't mul(60) it would add seconds and not minutes
            everyMinute = everyMinute.WithColumn("Time",
                Functions.Lit(unixFromTime)
                    .Plus(Functions.Col("Id").Cast("Int").Multiply(Functions.Lit(60))));
            
            //convert the unix epoch to an actual timestamp and drop all the intermediate columns
            everyMinute = everyMinute.WithColumn("Date",
                Functions.ToTimestamp(Functions.FromUnixTime(Functions.Col("Time")))).Select("Date");
                
            //convert timestamp into individual columns

            everyMinute = everyMinute.WithColumn("Year", Functions.Year(Functions.Col("Date")));
            everyMinute = everyMinute.WithColumn("Month", Functions.Month(Functions.Col("Date")));
            everyMinute = everyMinute.WithColumn("Day", Functions.DayOfMonth(Functions.Col("Date")));
            everyMinute = everyMinute.WithColumn("Hour", Functions.Hour(Functions.Col("Date")));
            everyMinute = everyMinute.WithColumn("Minute", Functions.Minute(Functions.Col("Date")));

            //join both data frames so...
            var dfAllData = everyMinute.Join(df, new List<string>() {"Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute"}, "left_outer");
            
            //add in data using Last
            var window = Window.OrderBy("Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute");
            var filledDataFrame = dfAllData.WithColumn("newValue",
                Functions.When(dfAllData["Value"].IsNull(),
                        Functions.Last(dfAllData["Value"], true).Over(window))
                    .Otherwise(dfAllData["Value"]));

            filledDataFrame.Show(1000, 10000);
        }
    }
}
```

ed

Comment: Thank you, your solution works perfectly. 
I only have one more question regarding forward filling. Suppose there were more `Id`s (approx 100 different `Id`s) and more `Type`s (power1, power2, power3, ...) in the `DataFrame`. How can I fill the daily minutes for each of the `Id` and then each of the `Type`? So far, I filtered them to obtain one `Id` and `Type` at the time, but then we get a sort of a for loop, which we would like to avoid. Is there a way to add minutes for multiple `Id`s and `Types`?

Comment: Hi @V.J. i'd create a third dataframe with all the possible ID's and Type's - then do a cross join on that to the everyMinute data frame which you then do the left_outer as this example

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Will try.